# Why linux shows "File descriptor 4 (????) leaked on ..." and how to remove it?

Tags: linux, file, descriptor

I'm a new guy here.
I get many messages like
"

```
File descriptor 4 (socket:[78134]) leaked on lvm invocation. Parent PID 15230: sh
File descriptor 7 (socket:[77180]) leaked on lvm invocation. Parent PID 15230: sh
File descriptor 8 (socket:[78138]) leaked on lvm invocation. Parent PID 15230: sh
File descriptor 12 (/dev/sdb) leaked on lvm invocation. Parent PID 15230: sh
File descriptor 13 (/dev/sdc) leaked on lvm invocation. Parent PID 15230: sh
File descriptor 14 (/dev/sdd) leaked on lvm invocation. Parent PID 15230: sh
File descriptor 15 (/dev/sde) leaked on lvm invocation. Parent PID 15230: sh
```

"

Who knows why system reports that and how to remove?

Thanks!

Comment: I added O_CLOEXEC to open() and now no longer show file descriptor leaks associated with /dev/xxx.

But the socket file descriptor is still leaking, even though I added SOCK_CLOEXEC with fcntl() on socket()/accept()

Comment: I think this should be asked on `superuser.com`.